# DTS (Export and Import) options in SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

I used to do an export (in SQL Server 2000) of an existing database to another new database, once in a while. It reduces the size of my DB as well.

But the same feature is NOT available in SQL Server 2008. I searched the Import and Export wizards in SQL Server 2008, but found only the other two options (Table/View export and Select (Query) option only), the other option 'Copy Objects and data between SQL Server databases' is not there ?

Is that moved anywhere else ?

Happiness Always
BKR Shivaprakkash

Answer (score 0):

if i am not mistaken you can restore your existing database to new one just write new name in database name when you click on restore

Comment: Well it's not about restoring.   It's just copying all objects from one database to another, with current data.  That option, available in SQL 2000, will not copy the deleted records, if any, from the old database.

Comment: when restoring data restores too... when i need some test database i just restore my main DB and it works for me...

Comment: It works, that's not what I need.   I need an equivalent option ( 'Copy Objects and data between SQL Server databases') in Sql 2008, what's there in SQL 2000.

Comment: and what about sql compare tool? http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/ you can compare two databases with it and copy data you want to another DB